# Can gradle-release-plugin be configured to use SemVer?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, semantic-versioning, gradle-release-plugin

I have a Spring-Boot Gradle 4.10.3 project which is currently working fine. It uses gradle-release plugin for releases and version management.

However, I now have a new requirement that the artifacts generated for this project adhere to SemVer conventions. I know there are SemVer Gradle plugins, but I don't want to retool my entire release process if I don't have to. It would be great if gradle-release would let me specify a filename pattern.

The [config docs](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release#configuration) mention a parameter called versionPatterns, which seems like it might be helpful. But I can't figure out how to modify the example given:

> versionPatterns = [
>           /(\d+)([^\d]*$)/: { Matcher m, Project p -> m.replaceAll("${(m[0](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release#configuration) as int) + 1}${m[0][2]}") }
>       ]

So, what I need is my file name to change from:

AppName-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

To:

AppName.1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

So really it seems like simply a matter of replacing the first dash with a dot.

Can this be done with gradle-release config? If not, is there an easier way? I would like to continue using gradle-release plugin, because it is already wired in for all of my processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have achieved my goal by configuring the bootJar section.

I'm using an older Gradle version, so I am using some deprecated properties. But adding the following to bootJar seems to be doing the trick. Still interested in other/better ideas.

```
archiveName = "$baseName.$version.$extension"
```

Comment: gradle-release has nothing to do with the naming and as you figured out it is part of the jar task. The archiveName is deprecated and the replacement is archiveFileName. Check out https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveFileName
The BootJar extends Jar from gradle.